# jquery horizontal animations fail on ipad and tablets

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, ipad

I am having a terrible time getting some jquery to play nice with the ipad or other tablets zoom. There is supposed to be a horizontal animation. When the purple buttons to the left and right are clicked a terrible rezooming happens on tablets.

my viewport is set to 1200.

here is my jquery. As the animations pull in content in horizontally and fade, the ipad rezooms for a few moments and then figures itself out.

```
<script>
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

$('.link').click(function() {
    $('#page').css('display','block');
    $('#page').animate({'left':'0px'}, 600);
    //$('#page2').animate({'left':'11400px'}, 600);
    //$('#page3').animate({'right':'-11400px'}, 600);
    $('#page3').hide(100);
    $('#page2').hide(100);
    $('#page2').animate({'left':'1090px'}, 600);
});

$('.link2').click(function() {
    //$('#page').hide(100);

    //$('#page3').css('display','block');
    $('#page3').show();
    $('#page3').animate({'left':'0px'}, 600);

    $('#page').hide(100);
    $('#page2').hide(100);
    $('#page2').animate({'left':'-1090px'}, 600);
    //$('#page2').hide(100);
    //$('#page2').animate({'left':'-1000px'}, 600);
});

$('.link-back').click(function() {
  $('#page').hide(100);    
    $('#page3').hide(100);
    $('#page2').css('display','block');
    $('#page2').animate({'left':'0px'}, 600);
    $('#page').animate({'left':'-1090px'}, 600);    
    $('#page3').animate({'left':'1090px'}, 600);    
});

});
</script>
```

Here is my CSS

```
.wrapper {
    height: 1800px;
    width: 1080px ;
}
.wrapper2 {
    min-height: 1800px;
    width: 1080px ;
}

#page {
    position: absolute;
    left: -1090px; 
    width: 1080px;
    display: none;    
}
#page2 {
    width: 1080px;
    position: absolute;
    left: -15px;   
}
#page3 {
    position: absolute;
    width: 1080px;
    left: 590px; 
    display: none;     
}
```

Comment: Could you post a link to a fiddle or demo site so we can better see what it should look like?

Answer (score 0):

Here was the solution:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=1200, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1">
```

Needed to keep the scale from changing and needed to fix a typo.